AWS CodeBuild - Build Sql Server Database project
I have a SQL Server database project in Visual Studio (MYDB.sqlproj).
For CI/CD purposes I have added a Dummy.csproj project to the solution, I have included a reference to MYDB project in the Dummy project.
Dummy.csproj
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Ensures build order, the DACPAC is _guaranteed_ to exist when included -->
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MYDB\MYDB.sqlproj">
    <!-- Companion to .sqlproj CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory=false  -->
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    <!-- Suppresses a warning about this project not being compatible with SQL project -->
    <SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>true</SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)..\MYDB\bin\$(Configuration)\MYDB.dacpac" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\MYDB\dbo\**\*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>

I am then using a buildspec.yml file to build the soloution with the end goal of generating a MYDB.dacpac file in my artifact zip, stored in my S3 bucket.
buildspec.yml
build:
    commands:
      - echo "Restoring project dependencies..."
      - dotnet restore 

      # Build the SQL database project
      - echo "Building the SQL database project...."
      - dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=$PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR
      # etc, etc

However this is failing with the error -
The imported file "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v$(VisualStudioVersion)/SSDT/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" does not exist and appears to be part of a Visual Studio component. This file may require MSBuild.exe in order to be imported successfully, and so may fail to build in the dotnet CLI. 

AWS CodeBuild Project Environment

I have used a custom image
Envornemnt type ARM
Image Registry external URL - mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

What I have tried

I tried using just the msbuild command instead of dotnet in the buildspec, which then need an additional
curl command to download the msbuild.exe however was met with the
same error.
I also tried manually adding
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets to MYDB project and
editing the .sqlproj file to point at that but again this failed.

This builds fine locally, and I can see the MYDB.dacpac in the release folder of the Dummy project, how can I get this to work in CodeBuild?
